# BIRT report - Getting HTML report with paging output

Tags: eclipse, report, birt

I want to be able to integrate birt with my application. I need the output to be in HTML format - preferably with paging or ability to scroll as the reports may become lengthy.

Can anyone provide any examples or just a basic rundown as to the best method of implementation this can be done in?

I have used BIRT and can make the reports I just don't 100% understand how to deploy them even after looking at a lot of resources including Acuates own.

Comment: this is a very basic question, with no indication of attempt to solve or look for an answer.

Comment: I did a lot of research but at first it is a lot to understand - I was hoping that someone understood it more so better than myself and could provide a clear outline as to the implementations in order to help get my head around it. I had looked on acuates site and quite a few others. For example the answer below was something I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a report and the BIRT engine to turn that report into HTML. The engine can be embedded in your own Java application or use their free F-Type server to embed with one of their APIs.

Multi-page export can be accomplished using:

- their JavaScript API and either the free or commercial BIRT Viewer
- their default HTML emitter with an external CSS3 file for page layout
- customize or create a new HTML emitter with the HTML tags that you want

Integration documentation is at

- http://developer.actuate.com/resources/documentation/ihub31/integration
- http://developer.actuate.com/deployment-center/integrating-birt-into-applications/

Comment: Thank you for your answer I found it extremely helpful :)